# Alter Function - Informix DB

Tags: sql, informix

I'm a newbie to Informix world. How to modify or update a user-defined function in Informix database? Tried below query:

`ALTER FUNCTION function_name().....`

It didn't work. I'm getting syntax error.

Comment: Have you checked the manual?

Comment: @jarlh  Yes I checked. It has mentioned that I need do this "ALTER FUNCTION func1 WITH (MODIFY PARALLELIZABLE) ". But I couldn't understand what MODIFY PARALLELIZABLE means.

Comment: The `.....` bit is a syntax error.  You should show the exact statement that you tried to execute, because we can't guess what you were trying to do without you showing us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately doesn't exists alter function to change the body for Informix database. 
You need to drop and create it again.

Be careful, save the grants before to replicate them after recreate the function and make sure not have set the pdqpriority at the session where you will create it.

Comment: Thanks alot @ceinmart & Jonathan Leffler. I dropped and created the function again. I guess informix will be bit hard when someone comes  from MSSQL background like me ;D.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the Informix 12.10 Information Center and look at the available [SQL statements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0228.htm), you will find that the [`ALTER FUNCTION`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0266.htm) statement allows you to change the characteristics of a user-defined function, or change the shared-object that provides the definition of the function, but you can't change the body of an SPL (stored procedure language) function.  For that, you have to use `DROP FUNCTION` (or `DROP PROCEDURE`) followed by the corresponding `CREATE FUNCTION` or `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

And, as [ceinmart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30105621/15168) points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469192/ceinmart), you need to worry about recreating the permissions on the function after it is dropped and recreated.